# Tridion 2011 Slowness issue

Tags: 2011, cme

Tridion is responding very slowly. Error:

> The HTTP request to
>   'http://wcm/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Lists.svc/GetListEnumerationValues'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9870000. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.

Please advise.

Comment: My advise is to contact Customer Support. I doubt we will be able to sort it out here on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on Windows server event log entries and concentrate on Tridion section. You can find Event logs from Event Viewer -> Aplications and Services Logs -> Tridion (Tridion Content Manager). Can you see any errors/warnings there? If you have not implemented any configuration changes recently these sort of issues are usually related to CM database long response time and lack of communication between DB and Tridion CM server.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the issue related to slowness is related to database query timing out.

To resolve this, I would recommend setting up indexing for the database (may be weekly).

We had similar issue where one of the particular operation was timing out, so we indexed the database and that resolved the issue. After that we have setup regular indexing of the database to keep the performance optimum.